# Moderator candidate statistics are not available for Travel

Tags: discussion, support, election

[image]

The candidate election page has a link to a page that is intended to give statistics about the moderator candidates in the election. It links to http://elections.stackexchange.com/#travel.stackexchange. However, Travel isn't on the list of sites on there. What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've requested for it to be included [on the relevant site](https://stackapps.com/a/4004/6371).

Comment: Please also upvote @sklivvz's feature request so that we enhance our chances to be noticed.

Comment: [Why shouldn't we use words such as 'here' and 'this' in textlinks?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100)